# Display location around current location?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mkreversegeocoder

In my map i need to display the locations which i am getting from a xml which are currently in a 200 mile radius from my current location.
I have never done this thing before can you please suggest a way.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Look into [CoreLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007123). Particularly, the method `distanceFromLocation:` of the `CLLocation` class will prove useful to find nearby locations. Use `CLLocationManager` to find out the current location.

Since you will most likely retrieve latitudes and longitudes from your XML, `CLLocation`s `initWithLatitude:longitude:` will be handy to initialize `CLLocation` objects that you can later pass to `distanceFromLocation:`.

Answer (score 1):

This will be the best site you ever visit http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial